# C# WPF MVVM биндинг из другого окна

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Открываю второе окно в котором есть TextBox, ставлю ему DataContext. Как мне получить значение из TextBox'a после закрытия окна?

Comment: Ну если вы по правилам MVVM, то у вас должно быть все разделено (контролы и все, что видит пользователь - View, База и другой источник данных - Model, а прослойка между ними - ViewModel.), вы не в коем случае не должны работать с контролами (view) из кода. Вот если у вас все это грамотно реализовано, то при закрытие окна у вас все данные останутся в VM слое (если конечно объект не был уничтожен). Показывайте код, будем смотреть что у вас не так..

Comment: Если у вас оба окна привязываются к одной и той же VM, то проблем нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP да,  я додумался привязать к одной VM